# What is the appropriate way of asking sequential/consecutive questions?

Tags: discussion

I'm a fresh programmer mostly struggling with data management challenges in R and Python. So far I have found SO (and the SE network of sites) to be very helpful. Many of my questions seem to be of a sequential nature, i.e. over time I like to ask a slightly different, but similar question on the same topic.

For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873279/pivoting-a-csv-file-using-r) I asked about how to reformat a CSV file, and some time later, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131728/cutting-a-csv-file-up-into-different-columns-using-r), I asked about how to further reformat the same CSV, but in a slightly different, and more complex manner.

What is the most appropriate way of asking questions that seem to build on each other such as these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there's an "official" stance on this, and the answer is somewhat a matter of taste.  A good starting point is the golden rule from [Jon Skeet's guide to asking](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx):

> Imagine You're Trying To Answer The Question

For me a good question to answer is:

1. **Concise**.  Doesn't distract from the main point with extraneous details or code.
2. **Complete**.  Doesn't require follow up questions or mind-reading to be understood by someone familiar with the subject.

So, applying this to your question here, I think it's better to attempt to present each question as self-contained, rather than as part of an ongoing series.  More people will get engaged by a question that's readily digestible; and beginning with a back-story adds weight.

My suggestion would be to compose follow-up questions as if the first one didn't exist; or at most, if you think it would be useful, add a link to the previous question for reference, as a footnote.